# How special Entities can be included...?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0

I want to include all related OrganizationPositions when IsActive == true

```
this.ObjectContext.Employees.Include("OrganizationPositions")
```

DB Structure

```
Employee |       OrganizationPositions 
---------       -------------------------
ID              ID , EmployeeID , IsActive
```

Comment: can you give us a little more context? were not (all) wizards.

Comment: Employee table joined with OrganizationPositions table On OrganizationPositions.EmployeeID = Employee.ID , i want to include OrganizationPositions on Employee But only Records that IsActive Field is true

Comment: @Masoomian you can't load only part of related entities - either do  join and fetch data manually, or include all related entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) will load all entities for specified relation. It is not possible to filter out some entities based on condition.

You can filter out entities by doing manual join:

```
from e in ObjectContext.Employees
join op in ObjectContext.OrganizationPositions
     on e.EmployeeID equals op.EmployeeID into g
select new {
   Employee = e,
   ActivePositions = g.Where(x => x.IsActive)
}
```

Comment: it is true, but this code returned AnonymousType.I need Employee type.

Comment: @Masoomian unfortunately if you will try to construct employee in query, you will see error that Employee entity cannot be constructed in Linq to Entities query. Option here is getting anonymous type and map it to entity on client side.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be. However if you declare navigation properties correctly, and you really need the situation you told, you can use some code like the following:

```
//...
// First, retrieve all Employees with navigation property
var emps = new ObjectContext.Employees.Include("OrganizationPositions").AsQueryable();

// Then, clear OrganizationPositions of those that aren't active:
foreach (Employee e in emps) {
    if (e.IsActive != true)
       e.OrganizationPositions.Clear();
}
```

Comment: thank you dear Amin. It is true,but this code fetch all 'OrganizationPositions' from database and then remove.